# Object renders black with UV mapped image?

Tags: materials, uv

[image]

I have an image texture UV mapped on a cylinder. Im trying to render the cylinders in white but they render in black. Any way to change this? Not sure if my node setup is correct. I have several lights in the scene btw..

Answer (score 1):

I've had this problem in the past when using glossy, glass or transparent materials with an alpha.

Here is the correct setup for alpha textures with a glossy (same process for glass and transparent).

You can remove the transparent node if you don't need it.

The Curve node is there in case the black or the white are a little bit grey in the alpha.

NB there is an invert node for when I use inverted alphas. Not useful here.

[image]

[image: alpha glossy render material nodes]
[image: alpha glossy render]

Comment: Ok yes that worked! Thx

Comment: My pleasure, please upvote

Comment: Quick tip @Sami everytime you get specific issues like that, make a Resources folder with simple blend files like the one I joined in this conversation. I got plenty of them for Alphas, Parenting specifics, Special displacement cases and so forth. Cheers!